# If my answer has been down voted several times, would I be debarred from posting answers further?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, post-ban

If I get several of my answers down voted, will I be allowed to post answers further? Will I be blocked from the community? Please mention if the rule is  applicable for all stack exchange sites?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, given too many poorly received prior answers, it is possible to get (automatically and for some time) banned from answering questions. This affects only the ability to answer; the account will not be suspended.

This is the case on all sites. Yet, it is determined on a per-site basis; a ban on one site does not result in a ban throughout the network.

Comment: Relevant links: [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans) (from the Help Center) and [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997) (from Meta Stack Exchange).